# Linq to Entities: Parameterised Raw Sql query?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

I'm writing a WCF service which utilises Entity Framework 6 (EF) to query SQL Server. Most of my query methods are written in LINQ. All good.

I need to write a parameterised query. Had a read through this: http://adicodes.com/entity-framework-raw-sql-queries-and-stored-procedure-execution/ This is what I've got so far:

```
       public string GetLinkItemValue(string linkTable, string linkItem, string linkGUID)
       {
         try
         {             
           var LinkItem = new SqlParameter("@linkItem", linkItem);
           var LinkTable = new SqlParameter("@linkTable", linkTable);
           var LinkGUID = new SqlParameter("@LinkGUID", linkGUID);
           var objectresult = _Context.Database.SqlQuery<string>("SELECT c.@linkItem FROM ISESEntities.@linkTable AS c WHERE c.CCCPGUID= @linkGUID");

           return objectresult.ToString();
         }
          catch (Exception)
          {
             return string.Format("There was a problem retrieving the Link Item value for LinkTable[{0}],LinkItem[{1}],LinkGUID[{2}].", linkTable, linkItem, linkGUID);
          }       
      }
```

This obviously isn't quite right and is corpsing on the query string at `c.@linkItem`, I've got it to return the query string as the objectresult string but can't seem to return the result from the query.

Infact even when I simplify the query & remove the parameters:

```
var objectresult = _Context.Database.SqlQuery<string>("SELECT a.ArticleTitle FROM ISESEntities.vwArticles AS a where a.ArticleId = 01");
```

`objectResult` returns the sql query string value rather than the result.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: what error are you getting? can you please describe it in more detail?

Comment: afaik you can't parameterize identifiers (like your table name or column name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a SQL string you cannot parameterize the column name(s) or the table name(s).

Your only option is to dynamically build the SQL string to include these values

```
var objectresult = _Context.Database.SqlQuery<string>(
    String.Format("SELECT c.{0} FROM ISESEntities.{1} AS c WHERE c.CCCPGUID= @linkGUID",linkItem,linkTable));
```

And then of course remove those parameters elsewhere.

As for the second issue, the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn159825%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) tells us

> The query is not executed when this object is created; it is executed each time it is enumerated, for example by using foreach.

so you must enumerate it to see the results of executing the query.

```
foreach(var item in objectresult)
  // do something
```

perhaps you only want the first result (judging by the query itself) in which case this should also work (as it enumerates the result)

```
return objectresult.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Additionally you could check whether the table and column names are valid: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10953145

Comment: Yes, I wasn't telling the query to return 1 record so I understand having to iterate over the result set. I'm now getting an exception 'Incorrect syntax near '@p0'.

Comment: @Hardgraf - I would stick a profiler on your database to see what query is actually getting to the database.

Comment: Yeah got the sql statement from the SQL Server Profiler trace & get the same error on the parameter when trying to execute the statement in SSMS. The table names etc. are correct, looks like it has a problem with the .'s. As in schema.@p1